# Opportunity Trigger not displaying correct value on Parent Account

Tags: apex, trigger

I am trying to find the highest Opportunities' Amount of an Account and want to reflect the value in one of the fields in Account, 'Highest_Opportunity_Amount__c'.

For that I have written an After Trigger on Opportunity and written below method in trigger Handler class. But my value on the 'Highest_Opportunity_Amount__c' field of that Account is not reflecting the Highest amount.

```java
public static void highestOpportunityinsameAccount(list<Opportunity> lstOpportunity,boolean isInsert,boolean isUpdate, boolean isAfter){
    List<Account> lstAccounts = New List<Account>();
    set<id> setAccId = new set<id>();
    map<id,list<Opportunity>> mapAccIdOpp = new map<id,list<Opportunity>>();
        
    for(Opportunity oppr:lstOpportunity){
        setAccId.add(oppr.AccountId);
    }
        
    if(setAccId.size() > 0){
        for (account acc :[SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, Amount FROM Opportunities), Highest_Opportunity_Amount__c FROM Account WHERE Id IN :setAccId]){
            mapAccIdOpp.put(acc.id, acc.opportunities);
        }
    }
        
    for(Opportunity NewOppr:lstOpportunity){
        decimal amount = 0;
        if(mapAccIdOpp.containsKey(NewOppr.AccountId)){
            for(Opportunity ExistOppr :mapAccIdOpp.get(NewOppr.AccountId)){
                amount = amount > ExistOppr.Amount ? amount : ExistOppr.Amount;
            }
            if(NewOppr.Account.Highest_Opportunity_Amount__c != Null){
                NewOppr.Account.Highest_Opportunity_Amount__c=amount;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you have two issues:

1. `if(NewOppr.Account.Highest_Opportunity_Amount__c != Null){` near the end of your code.

   - This is causing you to only set the account field if it already has a value. If it has no current value, it will not be given a value.
2. You're not updating the Account record

   - We only get the "automatic update" feature in *before* triggers (insert and update) when we modify a field on the record instance contained in `trigger.new` or `trigger.newMap` (i.e. if you're passing one of those two into `highestOpportunityinsameAccount()`)
   - The automatic update only works on the record being triggered, not on related records (like the Opportunity's Account). For what you're looking to do, you need to use DML.

That aside, this is something that you should consider making a rollup summary field for (which can find the maximum value of a field on related Opportunities). Why write code (and test methods) if you don't have to?

If you *insist* on doing this yourself, then I suspect the easier way to do this is to use Aggregate functions in SOQL to do most of the work for you.

```java
List<Account> accountsToUpdate = new List<Account>();
Set<Id> accountIdSet = new Set<Id>();

for(Opportunity opp :myOpportunities){
    accountIdSet.add(opp.AccountId);
}

// Just in case
accountIdSet.remove(null);

// Fields in queries that use GROUP BY can be aliased
for(AggregateResult ar :[SELECT AccountId, MAX(Amount) maxAmount FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId IN :accountIdSet GROUP BY AccountId]){
    // To update a record, we only need to populate the Id field
    accountsToUpdate.add(new Account(
        // Using .get() on an SObject or an AggregateResult returns an Object
        // We need to explicitly cast it as another type for it to be useful
        Id = (Id)ar.get('AccountId'),
        Highest_Opportunity_Amount__c = (Decimal)ar.get('maxAmount')
    );
}

update accountsToUpdate;
```

If I were feeling particularly spiteful, this could probably be made a two-liner (but don't do this, wasting queries is a shame and this would be hard to maintain)

```java
// Try this at home (but not at work)

// Making use of field aliasing to trick the map constructor
Set<Id> accountIdSet = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>([SELECT AccountId Id FROM Opportunity GROUP BY AccountId]).keySet();

// Field aliasing + round trip deserialization to turn it into a
//   Map<Id, Account>, and then getting the map values to perform DML
update ((Map<Id, Account>)JSON.deserialize(JSON.serialize(new Map<Id, AggregateResult>([SELECT AccountId Id, MAX(Amount) Highest_Opportunity_Amount__c FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId IN :accountIdSet GROUP BY AccountId])), Map<Id, Account>.class)).values();
```

Comment: Thanks Derek for the resolution, Its working perfectly fine. I have multiple objects with lookup relationship on Account that is the reason I am using Trigger otherwise I could have used Roll up summary.

Answer (score 0):

To get the highest Amount among opportunities associated to any account, you can create a roll up summary field on Account Object.
[image]

This roll up summary field will show highest amount of opportunities and it will show that amount on account on that field.